# SQL Procedure not working/very slow with SQL Command

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I have the following scenario;

```
Dim cmd as New SQLCommand
cmd.Connection = myopenconnection
cmd.CommandText = "usp_getdata"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", 2008)
cmd.CommandType = StoredProcedure
Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

The application get stuck and keep waiting for a response when the above is excuted. I have tryed to execute the SQL command from SQL Management studio and it works fine and on another copy of the database.

Comment: What does the SP look like? Take a look at [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) - perhaps this will explain why you are getting different results from the app than from SSMS.

Comment: Checked for locks, etc, on the target database?  When you run it from management studio, are you sure to use the same login as the .Net applicaiton?

Comment: Please explain what you do with the `reader` variable.

Comment: The reader variable is returned if the .read is sucessful

Comment: @dems, Yes, I am sure that I am using the same login credentials.

Comment: `.Read` only advances the reader to the first result (if one exists).

Comment: Which line in the question does the application get stuck on and for how long? That is fairly critical information to determining an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very slow/not working code;

```
  Dim cmd As New SQLCommand
  cmd.Connection = myopenconnection
  cmd.CommandText = "usp_getdata"
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", 2008)
  cmd.CommandType = StoredProcedure
  Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

The problem was solved by modifiying the above code to;

```
 Dim cmd As New SQLCommand
 cmd.Connection = myopenconnection
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", 2008)
 cmd.CommandText = "Exec usp_getdata @Year With Recompile"
 cmd.CommandType = Text
 Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 2):

### Execute a stored procedure with no data return

Instead of calling `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, call `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

As per [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx):

> **ExecuteReader**
>
> Executes commands that return rows. For increased performance,
>   ExecuteReader invokes commands using the Transact-SQL sp_executesql
>   system stored procedure. Therefore, ExecuteReader might not have the
>   effect that you want if used to execute commands such as Transact-SQL
>   SET statements.
>
> **ExecuteNonQuery**
>
> Executes commands such as Transact-SQL INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, and SET
>   statements.

**EDIT**:

### Execute a stored procedure to retrieve data

Or if what you're trying to do is return a scalar value, you can use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`.  But if you're looking to get data, you need to utilize a `SqlDataReader` object, like so:

```
Dim queryString As String = "usp_getdata"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        ' Call Read before accessing data.
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", _
                reader(0), reader(1)))
        End While

        ' Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close()
    End Using
```

[SqlDataReader Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx#Y3836)

Comment: And if it is supposed to return results? `usp_getdate` implies that `ExecuteReader` is the right choice.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though, does it?

Comment: @Oded well I would think it does, because if the OP is just calling `ExecuteReader()` without stepping through it and retrieving values, it would appear as though nothing is happening.

Comment: My understanding is that the application hangs on that line, not that the reader is not being utilized. I could be wrong of course.

Comment: the SP should return data as it contains a SELECT statement.

Comment: @Agius then utilize the ExecuteReader example of my post. Does that help?

Comment: At the moment I don't have access to the server cause I am not at work. I will check tomorrow.

From some of my research it seems that the issue might also be that I don't have SET ARITHABORT OFF in my SP.